# Problem with loading the class with php composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I have such a directory website:

```
- my application
- apps
--- Backend
--- Core
---- Core \ Config
---- Core \ Drivers (Db.php)
---- Core \ Main
--- Frontend
```

My composer.json file:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Core\\": "apps/Core/",
            "Web\\": "apps/Frontend",
            "Cms\\": "apps/Backend"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0",
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "~1.23",
        "mpdf/mpdf": "~7.0",
        "twig/twig": "~2.5"
    },
    "config": {
        "vendor-dir": "apps/vendor"
    }
}
```

The moment I want to call my application \ secret \ index.php in the file:

```
require_once ("../apps/vendor/autoload.php");
use Core\Drivers;
use Core\Main;
$bl = new Core\Drivers\Db();
```

The Db.php file looks like:

```
namespace Core\Drivers;


class Db
{

...

}
```

I'm getting an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Core \ Drivers \ Db' not found in

Why?

**EDIT**

```
// autoload_psr4.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname(dirname($vendorDir));

return array(
    'Web\\' => array($baseDir . '/apps/Frontend'),
    'Twig\\' => array($vendorDir . '/twig/twig/src'),
    'Symfony\\Polyfill\\Mbstring\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-mbstring'),
    'Symfony\\Polyfill\\Ctype\\' => array($vendorDir . '/symfony/polyfill-ctype'),
    'Psr\\Log\\' => array($vendorDir . '/psr/log/Psr/Log'),
    'PHPMailer\\PHPMailer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/phpmailer/phpmailer/src'),
    'Mpdf\\' => array($vendorDir . '/mpdf/mpdf/src'),
    'Monolog\\' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog'),
    'DeepCopy\\' => array($vendorDir . '/myclabs/deep-copy/src/DeepCopy'),
    'Core\\' => array($baseDir . '/apps/Core'),
    'Cms\\' => array($baseDir . '/apps/Backend'),
);
```

Comment: Please check whether Db class is correctly located in `apps/Core/Drivers/Db.php` and not `apps/core/drivers/db.php`. File/folder name should be case-sensitive.

Comment: And run `composer dump-autoload` from the terminal after every autoload changes in composer.json.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks pretty cool but I would suggest you change the contents of `secret/index.php` to:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../apps/vendor/autoload.php';   //A cleaner approach for requiring files

use Core\Drivers\Db;    //So, you don't have to use slash when using your class in your code.
use Core\Main;

$bl = new Db();
```

Answer (score -1):

use from root directory like this:

```
use \Core\Drivers;
use \Core\Main;
$bl = new \Core\Drivers\Db();
```

> Use from the root directory the php will search for the given classes
>   in the current namespace

Comment: Leading slash in `use` statements is pointless. And using it make sense only in namespaced context, which is not the case.